# How to pass multiple array in CodeIgniter model?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have two arrays to insert data to database. The first array is like

```
 $data= array(
 'date'=>$date,
 'amount'=>$amt,
 );
```

Next array is like same. But I have to check some conditions. I put the array like

```
        if($mode == 1)
        {

           $data= array(
           'Percentage'=>$percent,
           'deduction'=>$deduct,
          );
       }
      else if($mode ==2)
      {
           $data= array(
           'Percentage1'=>$percent,
           'deduction1'=>$deduct,
          );
      }
```

Then I use

```
  $this->amout_model->insert_amount($data,$app_id);
```

But insert the data of one Array. How to insert two array of data?

Comment: can you placed in a loop?

Comment: Percentage,deduction,Percentage1,deduction1 is diffrent fields in your table

Comment: yes.different fields

Comment: test `var_dump($data)` above the `  $this->amout_model->insert_amount($data,$app_id);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is 100% works for you...

```
$data= array(
 'date'=> $date,
 'amount'=> $amt,
 );

$mode_arr= array();

if($mode == 1)
{

   $mode_arr= array(
   'Percentage'=>$percent,
   'deduction'=>$deduct,
  );
}
else if($mode ==2)
{
   $mode_arr= array(
   'Percentage1'=>$percent,
   'deduction1'=>$deduct,
  );
}

$data =array_merge($data,$mode_arr);
```

Comment: ok.I will try and have some doubts.asku after 20 minz plz help me

Comment: yeah sure! any time... :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

```
$arr1 = array(
 'date'=> $date,
 'amount'=> $amt,
 );

$arr2 = array();

if($mode == 1)
{
   $arr2 = array(
   'Percentage'=>$percent,
   'deduction'=>$deduct,
  );
}
else if($mode ==2)
{
   $arr2 = array(
   'Percentage1'=>$percent,
   'deduction1'=>$deduct,
  );
}

$temp_arr =array_merge($arr1,$arr2);
```

> Now, $temp_arr is complete array which you can insert easily into
>   database.

Answer (score -1):

Lets the name the array you will pass as `$data`

```
 $data1 = array(
 'date'=>$date,
 'amount'=>$amt,
 );

 $data2= array(
 'Percentage'=>$percent,
 'deduction'=>$deduct,
 );

 $data['data1'] = $data1;
 $data['data2'] = $data2;
```